# How do I redirect request if a subdomain does not exist?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I've setup a current project with subdomains based on [this](http://railscasts.com/episodes/123-subdomains-revised) Railscast. I have two models, `State` and `City` that each have a `:subdomain` field in their dataset. If a user enters a subdomain that matches this `:subdomain` it presents the appropriate content.

How can I redirect a request if the subdomain does not exist in either the `State` or `City` model? For example, I would want `blue.domain.com` to be redirected to the `rails_root`.

Can someone provide a little guidance on how to redirect if the requested domain does not exist?

Comment: If you post your controller before_filter where you find the city or state, we can tell you where to add the redirection

Comment: i guess i missed that detail... i didn't actually set it up with a before_filter... Is that where I'd add some kind of validation logic?

Comment: Yep, in your application_controller you'd do your find_by and then redirect if not found

Comment: Gotcha... Thanks. You wanna answer so I can give you credit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your controller, you'll want to add a before_filter where you find the city or state, and then redirect away if not found. Something like:

```
before_filter :find_subdomain

def find_subdomain
  @city_or_state = City.find_by_subdomain(request.subdomain) || State.find_by_subdomain(request.subdomain)
  redirect_to root_path(subdomain: false) if @city_or_state.nil?
end
```

Comment: In case `root_path` not responses right -> `root_url(subdomain: false)`

Answer (score 1):

This is just another way to do the same:

```
before_filter :find_subdomain

private
def find_subdomain
  @city_or_state = City.find_by_subdomain(request.subdomain) || State.find_by_subdomain(request.subdomain)
  redirect_to request.domain if @city_or_state.nil?
end
```